# Coudn't get a simple combination exercise?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> Find how many 5-player teams could be made out of group 7 people:
>
> - if the captain is already selected (from the same group of 7 people)

So, I know that I have to use: $_{n}C_{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$, to find all the combinations of $n$ items, selected $k$ at a time.

I can't seem to figure out the implication of the captain (pre)selection, i.e. how are $n$ and $k$ affected by the above constraint?

Every useful advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: If the captain has already been selected, then the remaining 4 members must come from a group of 6 people (everyone except the captain).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! How many combinations do I need to calculate? One for the captain, one for the rest of the team?

Comment: The way I interpret the problem is that one of the group is named Fred, and Fred will be the captain.  So there is nothing to select, when it comes to the captain.